# how to show two variables output in one line in java?

Tags: java, output, println

```
Sytem.out.println("value of x , y : "+x +y);
```

Output will be "value of x,y : 1020" where x is 10 and y is 20

But I want to print this `"value of x,y : 10 20"`

Comment: ehm ... I doubt that that statement gives that result. Have you tried a simple String concatenation by putting a space between x and y?

Comment: _Output will be "value of x,y : 1020"_ - you will get an error instead of the claimed output. To get the desired output ---> `System.out.println("value of x & y : " + x + " " + y);`

Comment: You can also use `print` instead of `println`. `System.out.print(foo);` and then `System.out.print(bar);` will be displayed in one line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than string concatenation , you can also use `String.format` to do this:

```
System.out.println(String.format("value of x & y : %d  %d" , x, y));
```

or `System.out.printf`:

```
System.out.printf("value of x & y : %d  %d\n" , x, y);
```

Comment: Another alternative, `print` instead of `println`.

Answer (score 1):

On `System.out.println`, you can print only `String` values so it is needed to format the variables to one `string` as follows.

```
Sytem.out.println(String.format("value of x & y : %d %d", x, y));
```

Comment: Might as well use `printf`.

Answer (score 0):

your code is wrong

This is the correct:

```
System.out.println("value of x & y: "  + x + y);
```

every variable has to have the "+" to get concadenated with other.

Comment: and if you want a space beetwen x and y you should put this: `System.out.println("value of x & y:"  + x + " " +  y);`

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this-

```
System.out.println("value of x,y"+x+" "+y);
```

or you write like this-

```
System.out.print("value of x,y"+x+" "+y);
```